# Spring MVC and Mongo form user login example against database

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm planning to develop a **Spring MVC, Security and Mongo (No SQL)** user database form login example. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of searching, I found this wonderful working example and even it's working for all latest dependencies.

Here you go:

- Web-Blog: http://antuansoft.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/mongodb-spring-security-code-example.html
- Git Repository: https://github.com/antuansoft/SpringSecurity-MongoDB-MVC